# Retain or append 0 at the end of decimal c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a decimal field. I want it to be appened with .00 when it having no decimal point.
Like:

decimal d;

when d = 123    output should be 123.00

when d = 123.5  output should be 123.50

when d = 123.51 output should be 123.51

Note: Want the output in decimal only.

Comment: `d.ToString("f2")`

Comment: You can skip the 'rounding' in the duplicate title. Most answers provide in a way to show two decimals.

Comment: Hi @PatrickHofman , I didn't get a suitable answer for the question. If you don't mind can you post the link for the answer.

Comment: It is on top of this page in the yellow bar.

Comment: I want return in decimal , Not in String. That's why I posted this question.

Comment: The decimal doesn't 'remember' such stuff. It is just the number, how you format it when you print to screen is something else.

Comment: @PatrickHofman - I am not printing it. I am assigning it to another decimal value. Please guide me.

Comment: So what is the problem. `1.5` is the same as `1.500000` right?